# KDB - replacing row headers automatically in csv

Tags: kdb

I have a few `.csv` files that are exported each day from a program that I load into my KDB server.  The problem I have is the row headers are fixed and not ideal for what I want to use as my row labels in the table.  I basically now need to replace the first line of the `.csv` each time I save it.

What is the best way for me to automatically do this?  Essentially right now I am opening the .csv and pasting a row from another csv over the row headers.  This is a nuisance since I have four different csv files that need the labels replaced every day.  Below is the command to import one of the csv files in the INIT. I'm guessing there is a way to do this with `xcol` but not sure the correct syntax.  Thanks.

```
invoicedata: ("SSPPIFFFSSSSIIIFFFFISFSFS"; enlist ",") 0:`InvoiceData.csv;
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative and sometimes more efficient way is to read in the whole file including the headers as the data itself, but drop the first row.

When you read in a csv file with zero-colon, you can tell it to expect headers with `enlist","` or not expect with `","`. When you don't expect a header, you can pass in a list of columns to the resulting dictionary, and then flip the result to transform it to a table. After which you drop the first row, as in your case it's the unnecessary header.

```
q)// don't want to use `aaa`bbb as columns
q)1_flip `col1`col2!("JJ";",")0:("aaa,bbb";"123,345")
col1 col2
---------
123  345
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I jumped the gun. Played a little more with `xcol`and that seems to do it.  Just did a simple

```
invoicedata: ("SSPPIFFFSSSSIIIFFFFISFSFS"; enlist ",") 0:`InvoiceData.csv;
invoicedata: `a`b`c`d xcol invoicedata
```

which seems to work.